# jQuery : Object has no method for $.fn

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this function in my js file

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.foobar = function() {
   // some code 
  };
})(jQuery);
```

and when i call the following

```
jQuery(function() {
  $.getScript("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js");
  $.getScript("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js");
     jQuery('object').foobar(); 
});
```

it gives me the following

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'foobar'

i'm trying this on Rails file (*.js.erb)

Comment: Check the execution order of your js.

Comment: can you show a little bit more of your "// some code"? it could be possible that you have a syntax error so the function does not get declared correctly

Comment: edited to show you how i call jquery before the fucntion

Comment: pretty sure you can't load jQuery using jQuery...

Comment: according to this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top
i can

Comment: according to that question you can load scripts using jQuery but how are you going to use jQuery to load itself when it isn't loaded?

Comment: So, is jQuery available in the first place and you are loading an additional jquery min version?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are overwriting your jQuery array with that second one, try doing this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.foobar = function() {
        console.log(true);
    };
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
            $.getScript("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js", function() {
            $('body').foobar();
        }); 
})(jQuery);
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eB6Nv/)

Comment: yes same error ..  i think the problem is in (function($) {
  $.fn.foobar it self.. i'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Only run these codes in the fiddle, it runs fine. So, i guess that your code may be have some error at other place.I suggest you show more code for the question.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
<script src="jquery.js">
<script>
    (function($) {
      $.fn.foobar = function() {
       // some code 
      };
    })(jQuery);
    $(function(){
        jQuery('object').foobar(); 
    })
</script>
```